# Exchange code for access token and id token for google oauth java

Tags: java, maven, access-token, google-oauth

I want to store access token in session and if session is store then set accessToken and get the current user using Google OAuth..

I got the code from [Git Hub Click here](https://github.com/mdanter/OAuth2v1/). build on **java eclipse maven** build it war file and paste in tomcat.

[View Java Code click here](https://github.com/mdanter/OAuth2v1/blob/master/src/main/java/com/danter/google/auth/GoogleAuthHelper.java)

Code Work perfectly. i dont know how to get access token from google response code.

when i click om button it redirects to google oauth and after redirect to my callback url it response like

```
https://localhost:8080/oauth/index.jsp?state=google&code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7
```

from that code behalf if fetches the user information. but i need to store the access token which extract from that code. I got the reference from Google developers site but i can't figure out how to extract access token from that code and refresh access token to extend the token expiration.

or any other reference / tutorial for google o-auth that build on java web based plz share.

[Click here for reference from google developers site](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the `access_token` and `expires_in` from the returned GoogleTokenResponse, e.g., `GoogleTokenResponse#getAccessToken()`.

Take a look at [the documentation for GoogleTokenResponse](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.8.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleTokenResponse.html).